# double reference in EL expression

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets, el

I'm trying to make a "rich:dataTable" with a dynamic number of columns. I have a bean with a List of columns (with attributes headerName and fieldName) and a list of items to be represented in the table so I have next code:

```
<rich:dataTable id="data_table" value="#{bean.list}" var="item">

    <c:forEach items="#{bean.columnList}" var="col">

        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{col['headerName']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="??" />
        </rich:column>

    </c:forEach>

</rich:dataTable>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to put the value="??" to represent what I want. I want something like:

```
value="#{item.#{col.fieldName}}"
```

but I don't know how can I represent it with the correct Expression Language.

I'm using JSF2.1 and Richfaces 4.3.2

Con somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the brace notation `#{bean[property]}`. It allows you to use variables instead of constants as property names.

```
value="#{item[col.fieldName]}"
```